# swift 3 Application tried to present modally an active controller camera

Tags: swift

I am able to tap a button and pull up the camera roll and select an image and have it fill an empty imageView.

Next I tried to add a button that lets the user use the camera.

I was following a tutorial and I have the security rules set up for both option. However I still get a crash that says

> Application tried to present modally an active controller

I searched SO and found answers suggesting that I replace my line

```
present(picker,animated: true,completion: nil)
```

with

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(picker, animated: true)
```

However this just causes another error.

This is my full code for pulling the camera

```
picker.allowsEditing = true
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
picker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
picker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(picker,animated: true,completion: nil)
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

my code now looks like this

```
func useCamera() {
  let picker = UIImagePickerController()
  picker.delegate = self
  picker.allowsEditing = false
  picker.sourceType = .camera
  present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and I have also tried this

```
    func useCamera() {
      if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.sourceType = .camera
        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  }
```

but what happens now is that it just opens up the camera roll and in the console I see this

> Attempt to present UIImagePickerController: 0x1018c4000 on
>   Lended.AddAccountViewController: 0x10116f540 whose view is not in the
>   window hierarchy!

but the app does not crash, which is good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This is my full code for pulling the camera

Mmmmm, no it isn't. You keep referring to `picker`. This suggests, necessarily, that some variable or property `picker` *already exists*. So there is other code that initializes that variable, and there may be other code that *uses* that variable.

And that, I think, is the source of the issue. Somehow, you've accidentally put this view controller into use. The problem stems from holding onto a UIImagePickerController long-term. Don't. Code that does that always tends to run into problems. Simply create an instance of the picker right before you use it:

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController() // *
picker.allowsEditing = true
picker.sourceType = .camera
// picker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
// picker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(picker,animated: true,completion: nil)
```

Now I'll show you some *real* code that actually works:

```
let src = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
guard UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(src) else {print("no camera"); return}
guard let arr = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for:src) else {print("no types"); return}

let picker = UIImagePickerController()
picker.mediaTypes = arr
picker.allowsEditing = true
picker.delegate = self
self.present(picker, animated: true)
```

Comment: You'll notice I also commented out your setting of the `modalPresentationStyle`, which is probably unnecessary. And `.photo` is the default capture mode so you don't need that either.

Comment: Ok, I had put initializing code up top because I used it in two places and I thought that was 'dryer' , I will try this code when I get back home

Comment: That's good! We've solved the crash. Now you need to figure out why the camera is already in use. By the way, you need to be setting a delegate.

Comment: Okay, your problems run very deep. You are saying `self.present` but `self` is a view controller that is not in the view controller hierarchy. You are in deep doo-doo with your view controllers. You need to figure out how this happened, and it has _nothing_ to do with the code you are showing.

Comment: I just have my VC embedded in a Navigation Controller...nothing crazy

Comment: I assure you that you are wrong about that. And that is the problem. You _think_ this instance of AddAccountViewController is the one that you see in the navigation controller, but it isn't. Maybe it's another instance, a loose instance that you've accidentally created (probably by saying `AddAccountViewController()` - look for that in your code). Or maybe you are doing all this in `viewDidLoad` (big mistake).

Answer (score 1):

On a comment you mentioned:

> I just have my VC embedded in a Navigation Controller...nothing crazy – RubberDucky4444

I had the same error as you, and that was exactly my problem.

Given my navigation/view controllers:

```
let ccNavController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "creditCardNavigationController") as! UINavigationController
guard let ccVC = ccNavController.visibleViewController as? CreditCardViewController else {
    fatalError("Unexpected controller: \(String(describing: ccNavController.visibleViewController))")
}
```

When calling `present` for the view controller itself, I had the same error.

```
self.present(ccVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It worked when I did `present` for the navigation controller:

```
self.present(ccNavController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @matt I was able to get rid of the errors that I was having.
But in the end I accidentally created a double IBAction for the 2nd button...

I created a simple test by printing "left" for button 1 and "right" for button 2.

When I tapped the left button it printed left, but when I tapped the right button it printed left and right.

In the context of the camera...the camera would have shown up a while ago, but since it was running the function to pull the camera roll up first...the camera never had a chance.

The code that worked was this

```
  func useCamera() {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
      let picker = UIImagePickerController()
      picker.delegate = self
      picker.allowsEditing = true
      picker.sourceType = .camera
      present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```